# Revert line style in highcharts v4 with null values to old style (v2.2)

Tags: highcharts

The edge style of lines in previous versions of highcharts (at least through 2.2) end with a blocky edge when encountering a null value. In the current version of highcharts, the edge is rounded, this makes it more difficult to discern short lines in charts I'm making from points that are from another series. Here's how I want the lines to look using highcharts 2.2: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeg45jnf/)

I can't figure out how to make them look that way using the current highcharts: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghddzsLf/). I've tried things like disabling the marker and adding square markers, but no luck.

Here's the code to create the chart:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/2.2/highcharts.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

and this plot:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
           lineWidth: 10,
           marker: {
               enabled: false
           }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, null, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 36e5
    }]

});
```

Comment: It's a matter of the SVG line cap settings, not anything in the standard Highcharts API/options. I can't help with how to change the settings, but that might give you the right direction to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `plotOptions.line.dashStyle` to `'Solid'`. [Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghddzsLf/1/).

(This should be default, so why setting it explicitly makes them non-rounded is strange.)